# Describe the open sets of the Cartesian product of metric spaces.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I want help with the proof of this theorem

> Consider the metric spaces $(\mathbb{X}_j,d_j), j=1,\dotsc,n$.
>
> Let $\mathbb{X}=\mathbb{X_1}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{X_n}$
>
> The map $E:\mathbb{X}\times\mathbb{X} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $$E(x,y)= \left[ \sum_{j=1}^n\big( d_j(x_j,y_j ) \big)^2 \right]^{\frac{1}{2}} $$ is a distance over $\mathbb{X}$, so $(\mathbb{X},E)$ is a new metric space.
>
> ---
>
> **Theorem:** $\mathbb{X}\supset A \in \tau(E) \iff A = \bigcup\limits_{i \in I}A_i$,
>
> *$A_i$ such that $A_i=A_{i1}\times\cdots\times A_{in},\,\, A_{ij}\in \tau(d_j),\,\ \forall i\in I ,j={1,\dotsc,n} $*
>
> ---
>
> *Proof:* ($\Leftarrow$) We have to show that $ \forall i\in I \Rightarrow A_i \in \tau(E)$

That part is easy.

> Since $$A_{ij}\in \tau(d_j),\,\ \forall i\in I ,j={1,\dotsc,n}$$
>   For every $x=(x_1,\dotsc,x_n)\in A_i$ we can find $\varepsilon$ such that 
>   \begin{align*}
> &B_{d_j}(x_j,\varepsilon)\subset A_{ij}, \,\, j=1,\dotsc,n\\\\
> &\Rightarrow \prod_{j=1}^n B_{d_j}(x_j,\varepsilon)\subset \prod_{j=1}^n A_{ij}=A_{i}
> \end{align*}
>
> Now in order to finish this part we have to show that $$B_{E}(x,\varepsilon)\subset \prod_{j=1}^n B_{d_j}(x_j,\varepsilon)$$
>
> If we examine the arbitrary $y=(y_1,\dotsc,y_n)\in B_{E}(x,\varepsilon)$, we get
>
> \begin{align*}
> &y=(y_1,\dotsc,y_n)\in B_{E}(x,\varepsilon)\Rightarrow \\\\
> &\Rightarrow E(x,y) < \varepsilon \\\\
> &\Rightarrow \left[ \sum_{j=1}^n\big( d_j(x_j,y_j ) \big)^2 \right]^{\frac{1}{2}} < \varepsilon \\\\
> &\Rightarrow d_j(x_j,y_j ) < \varepsilon, \,\, j=1,\dotsc,n\\\\
> &\Rightarrow y_j \in B_{d_j}(x_j,\varepsilon), \,\, j=1,\dotsc,n\\\\
> &\Rightarrow y\in \prod_{j=1}^n B_{d_j}(x_j,\varepsilon)\\\\
> &\Rightarrow B_{E}(x,\varepsilon)\subset \prod \limits_{j=1}^n B_{d_j}(x_j,\varepsilon)
> \end{align*}
>
> *now I have to show* ($\Rightarrow$)

But I have absolutely no idea how to do it.

Could someone write down some steps?
And check the rest of the proof?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  to make things easier first consider $n=2$.  $A$ will be the union of open balls containing each of its points $x\in A$ because it is an open set in a metric space.  Say $x=(x_1, x_2)$.  Given an open ball of radius $r$ around $x$ let $A_1$ be an open ball of radius ${1\over 2}r$ around $x_1$ and let $A_2$ be ditto around $x_2$.  We can easily see that  each element of $A_1\times A_2$ is no more than $({1\over4}r^2 + {1\over4}r^2)^{1/2}=(1/\sqrt{2})r<r$ away from $(x_1, x_2)$ (in the metric $E$ of course).  Given that $x\in A$ was arbitrary, we can see that $A$ is a union of sets of the form $A_1\times A_2$ as desired.  The reasoning generalizes to larger $n$'s.

Comment: could you elaborate some more? I see that $$A=\bigcup\limits_{x \in A} B_E(x,r_x)$$ and $$A_1\times A_2\subset B_E(x,r_x)\subset A$$But we want a equality?

Comment: We have constructed $A_1$ and $A_2$ to depend on $x$, so let me denote them $A_{1x}$ and $A_{2x}$.  We have $x\in A_{1x}\times A_{2x}$ for all $x$.  Because $x$ was arbitrary, i.e., because our construction works for all $x$, we have $A = \bigcup_{x\in A} A_{1x}\times A_{2x}$, which I think is what you wanted to prove for $n=2$.

Comment: Have you worked out? I cannot prove that  $A \subset \bigcup_{x\in A} A_{1x}\times A_{2x}$

Comment: For each $x\in A$, we have $x\in A_{1x}\times A_{2x}$.  Thus, every $x\in A$ is in the union $\bigcup_{x\in A} A_{1x}\times A_{2x}$.  That means that $A$ is a subset of that union. (I.e., if we have $u\in V$ for all $u\in U$, then $U\subset V$.)